# How to store file content in a variable and make that variable available elsewhere?

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

My sidebar has elements that are the same in all my views, so instead of calling them over and over in all my controllers, I created a MY_Controller class and make variables available from there. Problem is, the content from my variables come from a file, so now everytime my site is loaded I'm making a call to read the file. It was pointed out to the me that this is not too good.

So what I'm trying to do is read the file in a model, then store it in a variable and then pass that variable to MY_Controller. Problem is I'm facing the same issue only now instead of reading the file from MY_Controller I'm reading it from the model. So I tried to create in a different function a variable that would be available in my entire model, and then a function that returns that variable, but it is not working. Here is my code:

Model:

```
class My_model extends CI_Model {
    public $report = null;

    function read_file()
    {
        $this->report = file_get_contents('/path/to/file');
    }

    function get_file()
    {
        return $this->report;
    }
}
```

MY_Controller:

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('My_model');
        $report = $this->My_model->get_file();
        ...
    }
}
```

Right now `$report`is returning null.

The `read_file()` function should be called once a day, because the file is updated daily in the morning. Any tips pointing if it is possible to do what I'm trying, or if there is a better way would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not going to give you code, because it would take too long, but I will explain how Symfony2 does it.  Heard of Twig? Well, regardless of whether you are familiar with it or not, the important part of it is how it compiles templates.

It compiles all template logic and text to PHP files filled with generated functions and strings.  The first time the template is executed this compilation is performed.  The second time, the compiled PHP is re-used.

The IO in effect still takes place, but only on the included PHP pages.  You can eliminate this again by bootstraping your entire source into a single file (Symfony does this with libraries, but not templates).

So, in order to "cache" your content to PHP, you need to write a PHP dumper (or using an existing one), or use `var_export` on simple data structures to dump your pre-loaded data.

Comment: I don't follow how would using var_export help? (And 'cache'! that's the word I was looking for). I'm sorry, I don't want code, I just don't understand your answer :(

Comment: (I was too late to edit previous comment) Just read examples on var_export, will using it instead of `file_get_contents` help me save resources?

Comment: @Ant100 The point of `var_export` outside of debugging and tooling, is to skip the computation stage of reaching the required data.  If you're only reading from a few files a time, that won't make a huge difference unless you are serving thousands of requests.  The reason I use Twig as an example, is because of the heavy lifting PHP has to do when parsing the text.

Comment: Perhaps Doctrine is a better example for you.  Whether configuration be written in YAML, or annotations, Doctrine only parses them once before dumping the entire configuration to a faster reading format.

Answer (score 0):

You should call read_file function before get_file, also there is no relation between calling the function read_file and the updating of the file.

Comment: that's what I'm trying to avoid, calling the read file, because then it's a 'read' everytime a user access site. I want to read only once (when file is updated) and since content won't change for the rest of the day, get content from variable.